# Creating new route in empty LRS dataset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-roads-highways, linear-referencing

I am using ArcGIS Pro and the Location Referencing extension (from ArcGIS Roads & Highways) to try to digitize (create) a new route in an LRS dataset.

I run the ArcPy code below to create an empty LRS dataset and network.

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("GCS_WGS_1984")
# Create empty TestLRS dataset and TestLRSNetwork for testing, and copying schema from
# Create empty LRS dataset (TestLRS), with default names for three feature classes (Calibration_Point,Centerline,
# Redline) and an LRS Hierarchy (TestLRS) within it, and three tables (Centerline_Sequence, Lrs_Edit_Log,Lrs_Locks)
gdb = r"C:\temp\test.gdb"
if arcpy.Exists(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"TestLRS")):
    arcpy.management.Delete(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"TestLRS"))
if arcpy.Exists(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Centerline_Sequence")):
    arcpy.management.Delete(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Centerline_Sequence"))
if arcpy.Exists(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Lrs_Edit_Log")):
    arcpy.management.Delete(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Lrs_Edit_Log"))
if arcpy.Exists(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Lrs_Locks")):
    arcpy.management.Delete(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"Lrs_Locks"))
if arcpy.Exists(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"TestLRS")):
    arcpy.management.Delete(r"{0}\{1}".format(gdb,"TestLRS"))
print("Creating LRS dataset named {0}".format("TestLRS"))
arcpy.locref.CreateLRS(gdb,"TestLRS","Centerline","Calibration_Point","Redline","Centerline_Sequence",sr,
                       "8.98315284119521E-09 DecimalDegrees","0.001 Meters",
                       "0.000000001 DecimalDegrees","0.0001 Meters")
print("Creating LRS Network ({0}) in LRS dataset ({1}".format("TestLRSNetwork","TestLRS"))
arcpy.locref.CreateLRSNetwork(gdb, "TestLRS", "TestLRSNetwork",
                              "RouteId", "RouteName", "FromDate", "ToDate", "DO_NOT_DERIVE", '',
                              "DO_NOT_INCLUDE", "LineId", "LineName", "LineOrder", "KILOMETERS")
```

The resultant file geodatabase has this structure:

[image]

In an ArcGIS Pro project (created from the Map template), I drag and drop the TestLRS feature dataset into the Map.

That causes the Location Referencing tab to appear on the ribbon.

[image]

From here I would expect the creation of my first route would be as simple as clicking the Create button on the far left of the Location Referencing tab and starting to digitize.  However, when I click the Create button the Location Referencing pane:

[image]

On that there are only two things I can do:

1. **Select one or more centerlines** (which I cannot do because my centerline feature class is empty)
2. **Run** the tool (which I cannot do because I have no centerline(s) selected

How do I digitize a route into an empty LRS dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conjunction with reading the [Create a route](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/production/roads-highways/create-a-new-route.htm) documentation, I realized that I should try digitizing a line (or lines) into the Centerline feature class of the TestLRS feature dataset before trying to use the Create button on the Location Referencing tab.

After digitizing one Centerline feature I tried the Create button on the Location Referencing tab again:

1. This time I could select a Centerline

[image]

2. Then I clicked the **Allow choosing of one or more centerlines** button (see red arrow above) and filled in the Start Date (today's date) and Route Name (I called it Route 1 as a test) before clicking Run:

[image]

3. Create Route completed successfully so I opened the Attribute Table of my TestLRSNetwork layer to see its field values:

[image]